# How can I successfully use the Jackson "ObjectMapper()" inside a "process()" method

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, camel-blueprint

PROBLEM: using Jackson's "ObjectMapper()" within the "process()" method causes an exception:

```
public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws IOException {

    //...this statement causes the exception...
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper om = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
    ...
}
```

The exception is shown in the Jboss Fuse console, it looks like this:

```
...

2017-09-12 16:45:56,262 | INFO  | edhat-187/deploy | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.0 | Installing bundle aaa.bbb.ccc.camelRest / 1.0.0
2017-09-12 16:45:56,323 | WARN  | edhat-187/deploy | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.0 | Error while starting bundle: file:/C:/tools/jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187/deploy/camelRest-1.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle aaa.bbb.ccc.camelRest [759]: Unable to resolve 759.0: missing requirement [759.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1245)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1217)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:509)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[9:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]

...
```

How can I successfully use the Jackson "ObjectMapper()" inside a "process()" method, i.e., to convert a map into json?

---

To provide context, below is the info on this simple application/bundle:

**aaa.bbb.ccc.CamelRestRoutes.java**

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;

@ContextName("rest-dsl")
public class CamelRestRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    public CamelRestRoutes() {
    }

    private final org.apache.camel.Processor proc1 = new Processor1();

    int notificationTime = 60;
    int overlapTime = 5;    
    String codeListString = "AA,BB";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    String fromURL = "http://localhost:7001/jaxrsRestService/service/getAll"; 

    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=" + 5000) //5 seconds... do we need to make this a system property (like notification service)???....
        .setBody(constant(codeListString))            
        .to("direct:thingB");

    from("direct:thingB")
        .split().tokenize(",")
        .to("direct:thingC");       

    from("direct:thingC")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
        .to("netty4-http:http://localhost:7001/jaxrsRestService/service/getAll/")
        .to("direct:thingD");

    from("direct:thingD")
        .split()
        .jsonpath("$.container[*]")
        .streaming()
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(proc1)
        .to("wmq:queue:mylocalqueue?jmsMessageType=Text&exchangePattern=InOnly");
    }
}
```

**aaa.bbb.ccc.Processor1.java**

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Processor1 implements org.apache.camel.Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws IOException {

    //***this causes the exception***
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.ObjectMapper om = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.ObjectMapper();  <== causes

    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) exchange.getIn().getBody();

    exchange.getIn().setBody(map.toString());
    }
};
```

**camel-route.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd
         ">
    <camel:camelContext id="aaa.bbb.ccc.routing.poc" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <packageScan>
        <package>aaa.bbb.ccc</package>
    </packageScan>
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="wmqcf" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>        
    <property name="port" value="1414"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="QM1"/>     
    <property name="channel" value="DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN"/>                     
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wmqcfw"  class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="wmqcf" />
    <property name="username" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="passw0rd" />
    </bean>  

    <bean id="wmqcfg" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wmqcfw"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="wmqcfg"/>     
    </bean>    
</blueprint>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>camelRest</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>camelRest</name>
    <description>camelRest</description>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <mq.version>8.0.0.7</mq.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope>                     
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-netty4-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope>                     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>              
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>allclient</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mq.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>                        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
        </plugin> 

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>        
        <configuration>
            <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources/xsd/jaxrsRestService.xsd</source>
            </sources>
            <packageName>aaa.bbb.ccc.generated</packageName>                    
            <verbose default-value="false">${xjc.verbose}</verbose>
        </configuration>                
        </plugin>              

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Export-Package>aaa.bbb.ccc*</Export-Package> 
            <Export-Package>aaa.bbb.ccc.generated*</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>                                                                      
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>             
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Camel features installed:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:list | grep "camel-" | grep "\[installed"
[installed  ] [2.7.0                ] xml-specs-api                                 camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel                                         camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-core                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-blueprint                               camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-spring                                  camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-bindy                                   camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-cdi                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-csv                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-cxf                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-exec                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-ftp                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-http4                                   camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jackson                                 camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jacksonxml                              camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jasypt                                  camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jaxb                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jdbc                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jms                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jmx                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-jsonpath                                camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-mail                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-netty4                                  camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-netty4-http                             camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-ognl                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-paxlogging                              camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-restlet                                 camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-rmi                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-routebox                                camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-saxon                                   camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-script                                  camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-snmp                                    camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-spring-javaconfig                       camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630187 ] camel-xstream                                 camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187
[installed  ] [1.2.0.redhat-630187  ] camel-amq                                     fabric-1.2.0.redhat-630187
JBossFuse:karaf@root>
```

Deploy directory containing IBM MQ osgi jars:

```
Directory of C:\tools\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187\deploy

09/13/2017  10:19 AM    <DIR>          .
09/13/2017  10:19 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/12/2017  05:10 PM            14,495 camelRest-1.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM           159,649 com.ibm.mq.osgi.allclientprereqs_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM         8,011,749 com.ibm.mq.osgi.allclient_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM         4,088,715 com.ibm.mq.osgi.java_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM           171,064 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.commonservices.j2se_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM            48,715 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_8.0.0.7.jar.DISABLE
06/29/2017  01:00 AM           639,807 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM           216,218 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.nls_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM           279,861 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.nls_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM            92,406 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.prereq_8.0.0.7.jar
06/29/2017  01:00 AM         7,963,226 com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_8.0.0.7.jar
09/15/2016  04:19 AM               873 README
          12 File(s)     21,686,778 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  142,681,493,504 bytes free
```

Other environment info:

```
jdk1.8.0_131
jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187
WebLogic 12.2.1  (running the rest service)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deploy error you are encountering is because you don't have the correct version of the **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind** jar on the classpath (as defined **below**).  Are you using a features file for deployment? If so, please include it in your question.

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   aaa.bbb.ccc.camelRest [585]: Unable to resolve 585.0: missing
>   requirement [585.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind)(**version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)**))

The way you are using Processor to deserialize to JSON is correct, however I would suggest creating the ObjectMapper() outside of the Process() method since you don't need a new one each time and creating one is expensive.

Comment: Thanks java-addict301!  Makes sense.  - I'll give a try this weekend and get back to you with a status!

Comment: not using a "features file" for deployment.  have "camel-jackson" installed (i.e., "camel-2.17.0.redhat-630187").   NOTE:  I have added OSGI bundles for IBM MQ 8.x (to the deployment folder).  Would these bundles potentially cause some sort of conflict?

Comment: Eventually figured it out, thanks to your suggestion - thx.  had to look up what the redhat version of camel-jackson was using...found it on this page(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jackson/2.17.0.redhat-630283).  then changed the pom.xml dependency to same:  "<dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> <version>2.6.3</version> </dependency>"

Comment: Thanks for the follow up saim, glad to be of help.  Some times these OSGI errors can be obscure.